# Similarities and dissimilarities between optimal scaling procedures in CATPCA and MCA

Tags: categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, optimal-scaling

I have seen that multiple correspondence analysis (MCA) can also be seen as a generalization of principal component analysis when the variables to be analyzed are categorical instead of
quantitative. In SPSS I have found both CATPCA (Categorical Principal Components Analysis) and MCA under the optimal scaling procedure. I am quite interested in the alternating least square method and optimal scaling method that these procedures use. How do the optimal scaling of these procedures differ? Can someone give a mathematical illustration of it? It would be great if someone comes with some illustrative equations about optimal scaling, CATPCA and MCA.

Can we get Cronbach's alpha for these two methods? Is the inertia more accurate measure than eigenvalues for MCA? Could you tell me the differences, possibly mathematically?

Comment: MCA is equivalent to CATPCA if all the variables undergo **multiple nominal** type of quantification.

Comment: Could you please illustrate how the quantification is done in both processes? I know for CATPCA the quantification is done so that the correlations between the quantified variables are maximized. Then how the initial quantification is set? What is the procedure for quantification in MCA?

Comment: I am also interested in how to perform these procedures in R.